# Can we determine symmetric multilinear map from this information?

Tags: combinatorics, functional-analysis, multivariable-calculus, multilinear-algebra

Let $X,Y$ be normed spaces and $T:X^n\rightarrow Y$ be a continuous symmetric $n$-multilinear map.

Then, is $T$ determined by $T(x,...,x)$'s where $x\in X$?

That is, can $T(x_1,...,x_n)$ be expressed by $T(x,...,x)$'s?

Comment: The answer to this is yes.  I am sure it's been addressed on this site, but it's always hard to find the right page when you need it...

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Any key word to this problem? I can at least google for this then..

Comment: I discuss the idea [over here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1934813/space-of-symmetric-n-tensors-spanned-by-elements-of-form-underbracev-otime).  The [first lemma here](http://www1.mat.uniroma1.it/people/procesi/tensor.pdf) (third page) also leads to an answer.

Comment: See also [this post on MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/98714/generalization-of-the-polarisation-formula-for-symmetric-bilinear-forms-to-symme).

Comment: If that doesn't make it clear I can post an answer to elaborate

Comment: @Omnimnomnom thank you very much! By the way, I saw another post Bazin is using that equation, but I don't understand his argument and why his answer is an answer to that question.. The wikipedia article on polarization given in that link is very helpful to me, but I don't get how the formula Bazin presented is the same as that in wikipedia ;((

Comment: And I need an explicit expression as given in Bazin's answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Going off of Bazin's answer from the link: we have
$$
T(x_1,\dots,x_k) = 
\frac{1}{2^kk!}\sum_{\epsilon_j = \pm 1}
\epsilon_1 \cdots \epsilon _k T\left( 
\sum_{j=1}^k \epsilon_j x_j, \sum_{j=1}^k \epsilon_j x_j, \dots, \sum_{j=1}^k \epsilon_j x_j
\right)
$$

---

Proof that this works: note that it is equivalent to prove the polynomial identity
$$
x_1\cdots x_k = \frac{1}{2^kk!}\sum_{\epsilon_j = \pm 1}
\epsilon_1 \cdots \epsilon _k \left( \sum_{j=1}^k \epsilon_j x_j\right)^k.
$$
With that in mind: for any exponents $p_1,\dots,p_k$, each non-negative with $p_1 + \cdots + p_k = k$, we find that the coefficient of the term $x_1^{p_1} \cdots x_k^{p_k}$ in this product is given by
$$
\sum_{\epsilon_j = \pm 1} \epsilon_1 \cdots \epsilon_k \binom{k}{p_{1},\dots,p_k}
\epsilon_1^{p_1} \cdots \epsilon_k^{p_k}, \tag{*}
$$
where $\binom{k}{p_{1},\dots,p_k}$ is a multinomial coefficient. I claim that if any of the exponents $p_k$ is zero, then the coefficient above is zero. To see that this is the case, suppose without loss of generality that $p_1 = 0$. It follows that
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{\epsilon_j = \pm 1} \epsilon_1\epsilon_2 \cdots \epsilon_k \binom{k}{p_{1},\dots,p_k}
\epsilon_1^{p_1}\epsilon_2^{p_2} \cdots \epsilon_k^{p_k} &= 
\sum_{\epsilon_j = \pm 1} \epsilon_1\epsilon_2 \cdots \epsilon_k \binom{k}{0,p_2,\dots,p_k}
\epsilon_2^{p_2} \cdots \epsilon_k^{p_k}
\\ & = 
\sum_{\epsilon_j = \pm 1} (1)\cdot\epsilon_2 \cdots \epsilon_k \binom{k}{0,p_{2},\dots,p_k}
\epsilon_2^{p_2} \cdots \epsilon_k^{p_k}
\\ & \quad + \sum_{\epsilon_j = \pm 1} (-1)\cdot\epsilon_2 \cdots \epsilon_k \binom{k}{0,p_{2},\dots,p_k}
\epsilon_2^{p_2} \cdots \epsilon_k^{p_k}
\\ & = 0.
\end{align}
$$
Thus, the expansion of $\sum_{\epsilon_j = \pm 1}\epsilon_1 \cdots \epsilon _k \left( \sum_{j=1}^k \epsilon_j x_j\right)^k$ is simply of the form $Cx_{1}\dots x_k$. From there, it suffices to find $C$. To that effect, we can apply (*) to find
$$
\sum_{\epsilon_j = \pm 1} \epsilon_1 \cdots \epsilon_k \binom{k}{1,\dots,1}
\epsilon_1^{1} \cdots \epsilon_k^{1} = 
\sum_{\epsilon_j = \pm 1} k! = 2^k k!,
$$
which leads to the desired result.

Comment: Could you demonstrate how you derived this? I looked at Bazin's answer, but he doesn't explicitly prove this formula.

Comment: @Dondor Asking "how I derived this" assumes that I derived this, which I did not. That said, I explain one way of arriving at such a formula [over here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3417654/81360).

Comment: @Dondor I've added a proof (but not a derivation) of the formula

Comment: Thank you very much! That is extremely helpful! I would upvote again if I could