# On tensor product of vector spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $V$ be a vector space over $\mathbb{C}$, Consider the vector space $V^{\otimes k}$. Now we know for $k=2$, $$(v_1\otimes v_{2}+v_{2}\otimes v_{1})=(v_1+v_2)^{\otimes 2}-v_1^{\otimes 2}-v_{2}^{\otimes 2}.$$ Then what is the formula for general $k$. That is $$\sum_{\sigma \in S_k}v_{\sigma(1)}\otimes\cdots \otimes v_{\sigma(k)}=?$$ How to prove using induction? Or any standard trick to get the expression.

Comment: I believe that this can be framed in terms of the [polarization of an algebraic form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polarization_of_an_algebraic_form)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one approach that works, but which I suspect is inefficient.

According to [this wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polarization_of_an_algebraic_form) on the polarization of an algebraic form (which is unfortunately underdeveloped), we should have
$$
v_1 \otimes v_2 \otimes \cdots \otimes v_k = \frac{1}{k!}\frac{\partial}{\partial\lambda_1}\dots\frac{\partial}{\partial\lambda_k}(\lambda_1v_1+\dots+\lambda_k v_k)^{\otimes k}|_{\lambda=0}.
$$
This gives us an expression of the form $v_1 \otimes v_2 \otimes \cdots \otimes v_k = \sum_j (c_{1j} v_1 + \cdots + c_{kj} v_k)^{\otimes m_j}$ where the $c_{ij}$ are integer coefficients.

After that, we can compute
$$
\sum_{\sigma\in S_k}\sum_j (c_{1j} v_{\sigma(1)} + \cdots + c_{kj} v_{\sigma(k)})^{\otimes m_j}
$$
to get your expression.